# Fitting two <div> inside document height

Tags: css

I'm trying to layout some html `<div>` elements to be like in the picture:

[image: layout]

Problem here is **#container height**. Setting it a fixed value or a percentage it will either leave empty space at the bottom or will bypass html height.

I tried setting it to 90% (10% is for #title) but it is not accurate deppending on client height;
What I have so far is this:

```
body, html{ height: 100%; margin: 0px}
#container{ height: 90%; overflow: scroll;}
```

Considering **#title height may also vary**, is it possible to use css to fit `#title` and `#container` inside the html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options, `flex` display or the CSS `calc` operator.

You could probably more easily solve this if you know what your header is going to be in any given circumstance.  In that case, you use `calc` like so:

```
header {
  height: 190px; /* Or whatever you'd like it to be */
}
.container {
  height: calc(100% - 190px); /* Where 190px is whatever height the header is set to */
  overflow: auto; /* Or scroll, if you want the scrollbar always visible */
}
```

In the less ideal case, you need to use `flex` for a flexbox display.

That would look something like this:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
header {
  height: 10%; /* Or whatever */
  flex: none;
}
.container {
  align-self: flex-end;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}
```

Let's walk through that one.  It's missing most of the vendor-specific stuff you need if you want broader support, but `flex` displays are supported in almost all major browsers now.

**First** we set `body` to have `display: flex` which informs the browser that this is a `flex` layout.  We also set the `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap`.  These properties should be fairly self-explanatory.

**Second** we set the header to a fixed display.  We do that via `height: 10%` but the value could be whatever you want.  The `flex: none` tells the browser this element is immutable in context of the `flex`.  If you think of the display as a river, this is a stone sitting in the middle of it.

**Third** we set the container to align itself at the bottom of the page using `align-self: flex-end`. This is so that it's always going to be at the bottom, regardless of other elements on the page.  This isn't super important as we're not wrapping (set in the `body` element) but we're covering bases here.  The important part is `flex: 1 0 100%`.  Put simply this is saying:

1. Grow to a factor of `1` (100%) in relation to all other flexed elements (none in this simple case).
2. Don't shrink at all (shrink to a factor of `0`).
3. Set a default height of `100%` (or as close to it as possible).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good enough for me! thanks. http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc and http://caniuse.com/#feat=flex

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `overflow: scroll` on `#container`, you can set `#title` with `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;` and give `#container` a `margin-top` that is equal to that of the `#title` height.

I would always suggest this route over `overflow: scroll` and use the browser's built in page scroll where possible.

Proposed CSS:

```
#title {
    height: 190px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#container {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Why must you constrain your container? The browser will only display 100% of the viewport. I assumed your goal was to keep the `#title` always on the page. If that is not the case, what benefit do you receive by limiting the height of `#container?`

Comment: Because if I want to use this plugin (https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/) or use a footer, #container must be of limited height.

Comment: You can add a footer on top of `#container` in the same manner. Give the footer a `position: absolute;`, and give the container a `margin-bottom` of the height of the footer. In doing this you would have no need to a scrolling library.

Comment: If I do that then part of the scrollbar will be hidden by the footer (`z-index: 99999`). Also the purpose of the scrolling library is using the CSS3 GPU accelerated scrolling feature. Such feature can only be achieved if you have a div inside another, the inner being full height and the outer of a limited height

Comment: Native scrolling will be more performant than any other option.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what your problem is, but *if* you know the height of `title` you can easily create it like this (using percentages):

```css
html
{
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#title
{
    background: green;
    height: 10%;
}

#container
{
    background: red;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#gallery
{
    background: blue;
    height: 5000px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="gallery">
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling<br>
        scrolling
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/yyu1txn6/)

Use `height: calc(100% - 100px)` for `#container`, if `#title`'s height is set in pixels.

If `#title`'s height is unknown, one might work something out using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` (or `flex`if you're feeling adventurous).